# Most efficient way to open a file and read the lines?

Tags: python

I've got this:

```
vlgaStream = open('vlgaChcWaves.txt', 'r+')
vlgaBuffer = vlgaStream.readlines()
vlgaStream.close()
```

But need a way to directly and efficiently read all of the lines from a file into a buffer?

Comment: No one wins at code golf.  Please define "better".  Does it mean fewer lines of code?  If it means faster, provide the `timeit` benchmark, please.

Comment: Yes, the fewest lines of code.

Comment: Even if fewest lines of code is slower?

Comment: The target file is not more than 10k lines. So slow isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a file yields lines.

```
with open('vlgaChcWaves.txt', 'r+') as vlgaStream:
  for line in vlgaStream:
    dosomethingwith(line)
```

Comment: I'm simply trying to read the file into a buffer.

Comment: That's not what your code does, at least not directly.

Comment: So, do you know of a way to directly and efficiently read all of the lines from a file into a buffer?

Comment: The most efficient thing to do is *not* to read the lines all at once, but to pass the file to another function that will pull each line as needed.

Comment: Works only with python 2.6 and higher, but i think it doesn't matter.

Comment: @werehuman: 2.5 with the `__future__` import.